# Angular 2/4. Support of "DELETE" and "PUT" http requests using XMLHttpRequest interface

Tags: angular, http, xmlhttprequest

`Angular 2/4` can use `HttpClient`, which uses `XMLHttpRequest` interface provided by user browser, to send http requests. (source: https://angular.io/guide/http).

Does that mean that if user's browser doesn't support `PUT` or `DELETE` requests `Angular 2/4` won't be able to send these `PUT` or `DELETE` requests?

Comment: If i am not mistaken, the support of PUT or DELETE is entirely up to the server side, and has nothing to do with the front end. So it is not related to Angular or the browser' s XMLHttpRequest implementation.

Comment: Yes of course Angular cannot do anything the browser doesn't let it do, but which browser doesn't support PUT or DELETE?